# Bidirectional TVS between field ground and analog ground

Tags: ground, grounding, tvs

I'd like to know why this circuit has a TVS diode between both grounds.
The field ground is the physical ground used in the circuit and the analog ground is used for 6 analog signals (between 4 and 20mA). Those signals are designed for sensors (a wide variety of sensors). My guess is because such signals can be very sensible to noise (and the circuit also has nosiy digital signals), the grounds need that protection. My second guess is that, due to the fact that I can't possibly know which sensors are going to be used (because it's a multipurpose design), you need that protection to make sure that the sensors don't damage the circuit. It is also realistic to think about human error, and that maybe someone connects a sensor not designed for such currents.

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likely that there is expected to be a DC offset between the two gnds (4..20mA current loops are often powered remotely over long cables).  Hence the circuit separates them.  Presumably it uses a sense resistor and differential amplifier to measure the signal and presumably this circuit can accommodate a range of common mode voltages so as to be able to work when AGND is offset from circuit GND.

The TVS and caps are there to shunt any ESD or other large transient to FG and thus protect the inputs of the differential amplifier.

This type of sensor is often used in industrial settings where large inductive loads generate a lot of EM noise that can in turn couple into the sensor wires and sometimes generate high voltages.